# Assinar parâmetros json com certificado digital C#

Tags: c#, json, certificado-digital

Estou tentando integrar com um webservice, que exige que a mensagem seja criptografada com o padrão PKS7, porém quando tento assinar digitalmente a mensagem, estou recebendo este erro:

Exception: O provedor não pôde executar a ação porque o contexto foi adquirido como silencioso.

```
public static byte[] SignFile(X509Certificate2Collection certs, byte[] data)
    {
        try
        {
            ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(data);
            SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(content, false);
            if (VerifySign(data))
            {
                signedCms.Decode(data);
            }
            foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in certs)
            {
                CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(cert);
                signer.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.WholeChain;
                signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);
            }
            return signedCms.Encode();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Erro ao assinar arquivo. A mensagem retornada foi: " + ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Tente chamar `signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer, false)` - [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858594/error-when-using-signedcms-with-smartcard-certificate)

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou, era isso mesmo!